# How to set contents of a specific content type unavailable in link uri autocomplete select widget in Drupal 8?

Tags: php, autocomplete, drupal-8, select-options

When you want to add a link to a menu in Drupal 8, you can enter a `Menu link title` and select one of the options from the autocomplete list for the  `Link` field widget.

By default, all contents of all content types (Article, Banner, Basic page) are available in this auto complete select list.

How can I set all contents of the content type `Banner` and `Basic page` unavailable in the auto complete select field widget? I want to show contents (publish is checked) of the content type `Article` only.

Below are attempts how I have tried one by one, but it does not work.

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
    if ($entity_type->id() == 'menu_link_content' && !empty($fields['link'])) {
       // Attempt 1
       $fields['link']->setTargetBundle('article');
       // Attempt 2
       $fields['link']->setSetting('handler_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['article' => 'article']]);
       // Attempt 3
       $fields['link']->setSetting('selection_settings', ['target_bundles' => ['article' => 'article']]);
       // Attempt 4
       $fields['link']->setSettings(['selection_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['article' => 'article']]]);
       // Attempt 5
       $fields['link']->setSettings(['handler_settings' => ['target_bundles' => ['article' => 'article']]]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with the following solution, but I am not sure if it is an efficient way to approach it.

Create a custom link field widget.

```
/**
 * Some class description.
 *
 * @FieldWidget(
 *   id = "my_custom_link_widget",
 *   label = @Translation("My custom link widget"),
 *   field_types = {
 *     "link"
 *   }
 * )
*/
class MyCustomLinkWidget extends LinkWidget {

  public function formElement(FieldItemListInterface $items, $delta, array $element, array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $element = parent::formElement($items, $delta, $element, $form, $form_state);
    $content_types = [
      'banner',
      'basic_page',
    ];
    $node_types = \Drupal::entityQuery('node_type')
      ->condition('type', $content_types, 'NOT IN')
      ->execute();
    $element['uri']['#selection_settings']['target_bundles'] = $node_types;

    return $element;
  }

}
```

Implement hook to set my custom link widget to the link input field.

```
function my_module_entity_base_field_info_alter(&$fields, EntityTypeInterface $entity_type) {
  if ($entity_type->id() == 'menu_link_content' && !empty($fields['link'])) {
    $fields['link']->setDisplayOptions('form', [
      'type' => 'my_custom_link_widget',
      'weight' => -2,
    ]);
  }
}
```